# Can GraphQl be used to request full objects, as opposed to fields?

Tags: graphql

We have a scenario where we have multiple nested objects, for example:

- A tree may have branches
- A branch may have fruits
- A fruit may have
  seeds

Our Api has many consumers with different needs:

- Some only want to know about the tree itself.
- Some want to know about the tree, and the branches within the tree.
- Some want to know about certain trees, and all the branches, fruits and seeds for those trees.

Ideally we'd therefore have some GraphQl-like endpoint which allows you to specify the **objects** you want and filter on these:

- { trees } //only get trees
- { trees: branches } // get trees and their branches

But from what I've seen GraphQl is about specifying the **fields** you want rather than objects. Thus for a tree query you'd need to specify all the tree and branch properties you wish to receive etc.

This makes it more awkward on the backend, because we then need a mapping layer for every single field which can be requested, and map this into a corresponding database field to build a query.

Are there use cases of GraphQL which simply request the high level objects in the queries, and the API simply returns those objects and every property on them?

Comment: You don't *have* to map every field individually. If any of a set of fields is requested, you could just query all of them, and only return those requested. The DB overhead is unlikely to be big. Leave the mapping to things that actually join other tables.

Comment: On the server side you can create multiple queries each one returning one "root" object, that is, one for the whole tree, other for the leaves and another for the fruits, so you can only see the most specific type in each. This still don't removes the fact that GraphQL you can only ever request individual fields within each object (it's *the* distinguishing feature of GraphQL).